# Can the Likert option in PloneFormGen be set to display the questions with the answers when submitted as an email and stored in the data adapter

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

We are using PloneFormGen in Plone 4.3.2  When a Likert field is submitted, it only submits the question number with the answer.  It does not submit the question.

Here's an example:

If the columns are:

Strongly disagree   Disagree    Neither agree nor disagree  Agree  Strongly agree

and the first question is

1.I use assessment everyday in class to monitor students learning.

the submitted answer will be something like

1: Disagree

if the submitter selected Disagree.  What we need is something like

1.I use assessment everyday in class to monitor students learning. -Disagree

Or some other format that includes the question.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Is the title of your field just "1" and the question proper is in the description?

Comment: The title of the field is: Edit Rating-Scale Field 

In the rating-scale object, it asks for questions like this:

Questions   List of questions; these will be the rows of the table.

1.I use assessment everyday in class to monitor students learning.
There 24 questions, but they won't fit in the the comment box

Answers   List of possible answers for each of the questions; these will be the columns of the table.

Strongly disagree
Disagree
Neither agree nor disagree
Agree
Strongly agree

When the answers are saved in the data adapter they are in this format:

1: Disagree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug in PloneFormGen](https://github.com/smcmahon/Products.PloneFormGen/issues/151): it does have code to generate a subordinate `dl`, but it's only run if a method `len` exists which doesn't but it wouldn't call it anyway.

Unfortunately, you can't really fix it through the ZMI, but if one were to courageously (or stupidly) find one's `formLikertField.py` in the buildout-cache/eggs folder, and in there, around line 139, erased or commented out the middle line in

```
    if not (safe_hasattr(value, 'get') and
            safe_hasattr(value, 'len') and
            len(value)):
```

one would get a mail with this:

> Overall title
>
> Question Number
>   One
>
> Strongly disagree
>
> Question Number
>   Two
>
> Disagree

Comment: Thanks,  I will look into it today.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: That was the exact answer I needed!  I tested it on our staging server and just moved it into production.  

Thanks very much for the help and thanks for posting the bug.  Wish I knew how to troubleshoot something like that.